# Looping through JSON Format Data and Constructing an Array

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where i need to loop through JSON Format data and construct an array from that

I have this format of Data as name value Pairs

```
var jsonData = [{date:'August 19, 2004',volume:22088000},
                {date:'August 20, 2004',volume:22088333} , 
                {date:'August 21, 2004',volume:22088555}]
```

I want to have all this Volume label data above in a JavaScript array such that it is starting from 0 and goes up to n Dates , it should create an array as shown

```
var volumeData = [[0,22088000],[1,22088333],[2,22088555]];
```

Any ideas , as how to achieve this .

Anything is fine either with jQuery of pure JavaScript .

Comment: You already wrote it in the title: You have to **loop** over the data. Where is the problem? What have you tried? Why do you need an array of arrays? The first element of the inner arrays is already implicitly available as index of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't JSON, it's a JavaScript object. However, you could do this:

```
var volumeData = [];
for(var i = 0; i<jsonData.length; i++) {
  result.push([i, jsonData[i].volume]);
}
return volumeData;
```

Comment: What some people refer to as "JSON in JavaScript" or "JSON object" is just a normal object in JavaScript (defined with an object literal). Only because they look similar does not mean they are the same. If `jsonData` would be "JSON in JavaScript", then it would be a string and needs to be parsed first.

Comment: Well JSON is a subset of a JavaScript object, which is why I made the distinction. I treat "JSON" as the subset, which is a language-independent data-interchange format. By "JSON in JavaScript" I mean the superset of the JSON subset, which implicitly includes the subset. JSON will always be a valid JavaScript object because it's based on the JavaScript Object Notation, you don't have to parse it from a String at all.

Comment: Thank you fd , Sydenam ,  EMMERICH very much . This website and all you people were very good .

Comment: Yes, JSON is a subset of JavaScript object literals, but nothing more. JSON can only exist in JavaScript as a string. Despite the name and the similar syntax, you cannot say that there exist JSON in JavaScript. This is a misconception. It is like saying that Java and JavaScript are the same, only because they have a similar name and C-based syntax. You should read: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.map(jsonData, function(elem, idx) { return [idx, elem.volume]; })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var volumeData = [];
for ( var i in jsonData ) {
    volumeData.push( jsonData[i].volume );
}
```

I like doing for loops for objects like this (I think it looks cleaner and reminds me of c#)

Comment: Incorrect, this would produce `[22088000, 22088333, 22088555]`

Comment: `jsonData` is not an object, it is an array. You should not loop over arrays with `for...in`.